# Passing scope of a function to the callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node let's say I have the following code:-

```
function readDirectory(callback){
    fs.readdir('./', filterList);
}

function filterList(err,data){
    //callback is undefined
    if(err) callback(err);
    callback();
}

readDirectory(function(){
    console.log("Hi");
}
```

But the following works if I define function inside the `readDirectory` itself because it's in the same scope:-

```
function readDirectory(callback){
    fs.readdir('./', function(err,data){
        if(err) callback(err);
        callback();
    });
}

readDirectory(function(){
    console.log("Hi");
}
```

So my question is, is there a way to pass the scope of `readDirectory` to the callback function that's defined outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is, is there a way to pass the scope of readDirectory to the callback function that's defined outside?

No, JavaScript has lexical scope. However, you can make `filterList` accept a callback:

```
function readDirectory(callback){
    fs.readdir('./', filterList(callback));
}

function filterList(callback) {
  return function(err,data){
    if(err) callback(err);
    callback();
  };
}
```

Comment: In my opinion this is the most straightforward answer. Not to mention that this is a common technique so future programmers will understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is clever. I keep forgetting that you can return function in `JavaScript`.